# Finding largest sequence of bytes in two byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, lcs

Example:

> { 54, 87, 23, 87, 45, 67, 7, 85, 65, **65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45**, 6, 4 };
>
> { 76, 57, **65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45**, 8, 65, 66, 57, 6, 7, 7, 56, 6, 7, 44, 57, 8, 76, 54, 67 };

Basically, I have two byte[], and need to find the largest identical sequence of bytes in both.

I have tried the obvious thing and wrote some code that bruteforces the result:

```
var bestIndex = 0;
var bestCount = 0;
for (var i1 = 0; i1 + bestCount < data1.Length; i1++)
{
    var currentCount = 0;
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < data2.Length; i2++)
    {
        if (data1[i1 + currentCount] == data2[i2])
        {
            currentCount++;
            if (i1 + currentCount == data1.Length)
            {
                bestCount = currentCount;
                bestIndex = i1;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentCount > bestCount)
            {
                bestCount = currentCount;
                bestIndex = i1;
            }
            currentCount = 0;
        }
    }
    if (currentCount > bestCount)
    {
        bestCount = currentCount;
        bestIndex = i1;
    }
}
```

However, in my application the byte arrays will be much larger, up to a GB even. So basically I need a hint / code on how to be more efficient than that.

Comment: looks like np complete to me

Comment: Ahh, so what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @rory.ap too slow ofc

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Tell you what, if you figure this out I'll do you a solid and nominate you for a Nobel prize.  Good luck.

Comment: @Dmitry: OP probably wants a common substring, not subsequence.

Comment: This can be done in O(nm) with DP as explained in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: @saarrrr now you got my interest. Don't forget to fulfill your promise when I got lucky someday and came up with a solution.

Comment: @Steve: why do you think this is NP complete?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli that's longest common sub sequence. It ignores any char in between which is different from substring

Comment: @Steve: I believe Dmitry posted a link for the subsequence, Gerardo's link is the simpler case.

Comment: @Groo oh ok. Guess im wrong. It is doable in this case then

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli Thanks, I think this is what I need, I'll read up on it

Comment: I have translated the pseudocode form wikipedia 1:1 to c#. However, the complexity is obviously the same and my algorithm seems to be nicer with memory and also a little faster, so i'll probably stick to that ...

Comment: @Whosdatdev the psudocode example on the Wiki page is using Dynamic Programming which is `O(N*M)` like your code, however if you used a Suffix Tree implementation you can do it in `O(N+M)` time, much faster

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, I misread it as O(N*M), thanks. I started searching for an implementation of the algorithm, as I've never seen it and it seems rather complex, but no luck so far :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple thoughts on this. I'm not sure if this helps or hurts, but have you considered working backwards through the largest possibilities first, so you can terminate as soon as you've found a match.

```
        byte[] b1 = { 54, 87, 23, 87, 45, 67, 7, 85, 65, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 6, 4 };
        byte[] b2 = { 76, 57, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 8, 65, 66, 57, 6, 7, 7, 56, 6, 7, 44, 57, 8, 76, 54, 67 };

        //figure out which one is smaller, since that one will limit the range options
        byte[] smaller;
        byte[] bigger;

        if (b1.Count() > b2.Count())
        {
            bigger = b1;
            smaller = b2;
        }
        else
        {
            bigger = b2;
            smaller = b1;
        }


        // doesn't matter what order we put these in, since they will be ordered later by length
        List<Tuple<int, int>> ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        Parallel.For(0, smaller.Count(), (i1) => {
            Parallel.For(i1 + 1, smaller.Count(), (i2) =>
            {
                ranges.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i1, i2));
            });
        });

        // order by length of slice produced by range in descending order
        // this way, once we get an answer, we know nothing else can be longer
        ranges = ranges.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2 - x.Item1).ToList();

        Tuple<int, int> largestMatchingRange = new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0);

        foreach (Tuple<int, int> range in ranges)
        {
            bool match = true; // set in outer loop to allow for break

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bigger.Count(); i1++)
            {
                if (bigger.Count() <= i1 + (range.Item2 - range.Item1))
                {
                    //short cut if the available slice from the bigger array is shorter than the range length
                    match = false;
                    continue;
                }

                match = true; // reset to true to allow for new attempt for each larger array slice

                for (int i2 = range.Item1, i1Temp = i1; i2 < range.Item2; i2++, i1Temp++)
                {
                    if (bigger[i1Temp] != smaller[i2])
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match)
                {
                    largestMatchingRange = range;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        byte[] largestMatchingBytes = smaller.Skip(largestMatchingRange.Item1).Take(largestMatchingRange.Item2 - largestMatchingRange.Item1).ToArray();
```

Comment: PS. This will probably be slower if there is no match, and takes more up front processing, so you may not see positive results in all cases.

PPS. You'll probably need to swap out ints for longs if you're working with much larger arrays.

Comment: Excellent idea! I think this will help in my case because I will always be doing this with one rather small and one very big array

Comment: Also, does anyone know how to get the ranges in length order without getting them all and then sorting? I can't figure out the pattern to work out a nested loop for this to cut out the up front range selection and sort

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the loops, this one should be faster.

```
byte[] data1 = { 54, 87, 23, 87, 45, 67, 7, 85, 65, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 6, 4 };
byte[] data2 = { 76, 57, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 8, 65, 66, 57, 6, 7, 7, 56, 6, 7, 44, 57, 8, 76, 54, 67 };


//figure out which one is smaller, since that one will limit the range options
byte[] smaller;
byte[] bigger;

if (data1.Count() > data2.Count())
{
    bigger = data1;
    smaller = data2;
}
else
{
    bigger = data2;
    smaller = data1;
}

Tuple<int, int> largestMatchingRange = new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0);

//iterate over slices in reverse length order
for (int length = smaller.Count() - 1; length > 0; length--)
{
    int numberOfSlicesForLength = smaller.Count() - length;

    bool match = true; // set in outer loop to allow for break

    for (int start = 0; start < numberOfSlicesForLength; start++)
    {
        //within a collection of similarly sized slices, we start with the slice found first within the array
        Tuple<int, int> range = new Tuple<int, int>(start, start + length);

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bigger.Count(); i1++)
        {
            if (bigger.Count() <= i1 + (range.Item2 - range.Item1))
            {
                //short cut if the available slice from the bigger array is shorter than the range length
                match = false;
                continue;
            }

            match = true; // reset to true to allow for new attempt for each larger array slice

            for (int i2 = range.Item1, i1Temp = i1; i2 < range.Item2; i2++, i1Temp++)
            {
                if (bigger[i1Temp] != smaller[i2])
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match)
            {
                largestMatchingRange = range;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match)
    {
        break;
    }
}

byte[] largestMatchingBytes = smaller.Skip(largestMatchingRange.Item1).Take(largestMatchingRange.Item2 - largestMatchingRange.Item1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the bytes one by one, you can save the index locations for each byte value in a dictionary of lists. In your case arrays of 256 lists might be better.

```
List<int>[] index(byte[] a) {        // List<long> if the array can be more than 2GB
    var lists = new List<int>[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        var b = a[i];
        if (lists[b] == null) lists[b] = new List<int>();
        lists[b].Add(i);
    }
    return lists;
}
```

then you can loop over the 256 possible byte values

```
byte[] data1 = { 54, 87, 23, 87, 45, 67, 7, 85, 65, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 6, 4 };
byte[] data2 = { 76, 57, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 8, 65, 66, 57, 6, 7, 7, 56, 6, 7, 44, 57, 8, 76, 54, 67 };

var indexes1 = index(data1);
var indexes2 = index(data2);

var bestIndex = 0;
var bestCount = 0;

for (var b = 0; b < 256; b++)
{
    var list1 = indexes1[b]; if (list1 == null) continue;
    var list2 = indexes1[b]; if (list2 == null) continue;

    foreach(var index1 in list1)
    {
        foreach (var index2 in list2)
        {
            // your code here 
            for (var i1 = index1; i1 < data1.Length - bestCount; i1++)
            {
                var currentCount = 0;
                for (var i2 = index2; i2 < data2.Length; i2++)
                {
                    if (data1[i1 + currentCount] == data2[i2])
                    {
                        currentCount++;
                        if (i1 + currentCount == data1.Length)
                        {
                            bestCount = currentCount;
                            bestIndex = i1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (currentCount > bestCount)
                        {
                            bestCount = currentCount;
                            bestIndex = i1;
                        }
                        currentCount = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (currentCount > bestCount)
                {
                    bestCount = currentCount;
                    bestIndex = i1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var best = data1.Skip(bestIndex).Take(bestCount);
Debug.Print(bestIndex + ", " + bestCount + ": " + string.Join(", ", best));
```

In theory this feels like it will take less comparisons for bigger arrays, but in practice it will have more memory cache misses, so I am not sure if it will be faster than a more linear parallel version like in the other answer. I did not think into this too much but hopefully it can give you some ideas in case I got it wrong.

**Update**

I just realized how bad this idea is for a regular machine with less than 32 GB of memory as the list of indexes will take more than 4 times the memory of the byte array.